# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT script: "No such file or directory" on existing file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-server

I've written a Dockerfile with the intent of hosting a game server in a Docker container, but the shell script ("run.sh") that is COPY'd into the container doesn't see the ELF executable it is supposed to run.

I've configured my Dockerfile such that it uses the latest version of the ubuntu package, downloads and extracts the game server's files to a new folder, and then deletes the .zip archive. It successfully builds, but when I attempt to run it with a simple shell script consisting of three lines:

**run.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pwd
ls
exec ./TerrariaServer.bin.x86 -steam -config ./config.txt
```

it always presents the following error:`./run.sh: line 4: /ServerFiles/TerrariaServer.bin.x86: No such file or directory`

`pwd` and `ls` confirm that `TerrariaServer.bin.x86` is present in the `/ServerFiles/` directory:

```
/ServerFiles
FNA.dll
FNA.dll.config
Mono.Posix.dll
Mono.Security.dll
System.Configuration.dll
System.Core.dll
System.Data.dll
System.Drawing.dll
System.Numerics.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
System.Security.dll
System.Windows.Forms.dll
System.Windows.Forms.dll.config
System.Xml.Linq.dll
System.Xml.dll
System.dll
Terraria.png
TerrariaServer
--> TerrariaServer.bin.x86 <--
TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64
TerrariaServer.exe
WindowsBase.dll
changelog.txt
config.txt
lib
lib64
monoconfig
monomachineconfig
mscorlib.dll
open-folder
run.sh
```

Other answers I've seen on StackOverflow have pointed to permissions conflicts (I've applied `chmod 777` liberally for testing purposes) and Windows line endings (the Dockerfile and `run.sh` were both created and edited through nano via PuTTY), but no changes I make seem to affect the outcome.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest

# Get wget package
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && apt-get install -y unzip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#RUN  apt-get install dos2unix

# Download and extract Terraria server files
RUN  pwd \
  && mkdir Downloads

RUN  cd Downloads \
  && wget -O "/Downloads/TServer.zip" http://terraria.org/server/terraria-server-1353.zip \
  && ls
RUN  unzip "/Downloads/TServer.zip" -d "/Downloads/TServer/"

# Extract the linux folder and delete old files/folders
RUN  cp -ra "/Downloads/TServer/1353/Linux/" "/ServerFiles/" \
  && rm -rf "/Downloads/TServer.zip" \
  && rm -rf "/Downloads/TServer/"

COPY run.sh /ServerFiles/run.sh
RUN chmod 777 /ServerFiles/run.sh

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR  "/ServerFiles/"
RUN ls
RUN chmod 777 .

RUN  chmod 777 TerrariaServer.bin.x86
RUN  adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' tserveruser \
  && adduser tserveruser sudo
RUN  chown -R tserveruser:tserveruser /ServerFiles
RUN  chown tserveruser:tserveruser /ServerFiles/TerrariaServer
USER  tserveruser

# Create the default config.txt
RUN printf "maxplayers=8\nport=7777\npassword=testpass\nworldpath=~/ServerFiles/Worlds/\ndifficulty=0\nautocreate=2\nworldname=World" \
  > config.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark...the only thing that I can think of that would explain the behavior you're seeing given all of the data you've so nicely produced and provided...

Is /ServerFiles/TerrariaServer.bin.x86 possibly a symbolic link that is not pointing to an existing file?  That would produce both the listing you show and the error you're getting when trying to run that "file".  It could also be that it is pointing to a file without the proper permissions.

If that's not it, maybe you should do a "ls -l" to see if that happens to provide any clues.

Answer (score 0):

With a binary that you've confirmed exists, this error typically means you have dynamically linked libraries that do not exist inside the image. Run your image with a shell, and from there, check `ldd /ServerFiles/TerrariaServer.bin.x86` to see what libraries are expected and likely missing.

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a different error?  Wouldn't it complain about the missing library rather than mention the base executable itself? - I wasn't 100% sure about my answer either, but it's easy to test, so I did.  I'm trying to think how to easily test this assumption.  Not saying you aren't right.  I just wouldn't have guessed this to be a potential cause for the given error message.  I love learning new things, especially in areas like this that can drive one absolutely crazy.

Comment: @Steve unfortunately from the Linux kernel, or perhaps it's the dynamic linking code, it's the exact same error message. Lots of people putting code in docker have experienced it in the past. To the point that it made my faq presentation: https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow.html#59